# How to capture packets

Tags: windows-phone-7, packet-capture, .net

Is there any way to capture and analyze packets with windows phone 7? For example can i use sharppcap or pcap.net in order to develop an application which capture packets? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packets capture requires low-level access to network drivers. There's no such thing for Windows Phone, you can only use sockets you opened yourself.

Comment: Why not, windows phone does have wifi, so it is probable that packets can be captured.

Comment: You can make an app on a computer to capture phone's packets over wifi. But a Windows Phone app can't do that.

Comment: Just because the drivers are not there. So makes sense. Probably you are right.

Comment: Not because the drivers aren't there, but because you have no access to them. A Windows Phone app has very limited interaction with the system.

Comment: Oh, my bad....so stupid to say that drivers are not there. Yes, yes...that is what I wanted to say, lesser interaction...Anyway... cheers :)

Comment: ok guys. Thanks for help anyway. I saw a similar app for android and i thought that i can do this also for windows phone....